# OpenCV build solution to another PC

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, dependencies, software-distribution

I have made a simple color detection script, using the inrange() function of OpenCV, and now I want to export the program to another computer, which does not have the OpenCV library installed (or the path editing involved with setting it up for use in Visual Studio, which I have been programming in, in C++.) The #includes involved are:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
```

When I build solution on the PC used to do the programming, everything works fine, but when I then export it to the other computer, I get error message:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to 
close the application.
```

Out of curiosity I have tried including the OpenCV library and setting it up as on the other computer, but without success, and I was really hoping there would be an easier way of doing it as well, since it would otherwise make distribution quite a hassle.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: rule of thumb: for each header file included, there's a lib to link, and a dll to distribute

Comment: Welcome to visual-studio :-D